# Wait for input before updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this card validator script that works fine:

```
$('#card-number').validateCreditCard(function (result) {
    if(!(result.card_type != null)) {
        $('.card-issuer li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#card-number').removeClass('valid invalid');
        return;
    }
    $('.card-issuer li').removeClass('selected');
    $('.card-issuer li.' + result.card_type.name).addClass('selected');

    //----------- Field to identify Card Type ------------//
    $("#hdnCardType").val(result.card_type.name);

    if(result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) {
        return $('.card-number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('.card-issuer li').removeClass('selected');
        return $('.card-number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
});
```

.. but it adds the invalid class even before the user has typed 16 digits, can I make it wait until the user typed atleast 14 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're calling the validateCreditCard function every time the user types a new character? If that's the case, don't check for it until there are at least 14 characters.

```
} else {
       if (document.getElementsByClassName('.card-number')[0].value.length >= 14) {
            $('.card-issuer li').removeClass('selected');
            return $('.card-number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
       }
}
```